# Flexslider - How to show the captions outside the slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flexslider, woothemes

Im building a Slider with thumb carousel, its working great!
Each slider item got captions, now I want to show the captions outside of the Slider.
The captions are showing but wont slide along with the slider.

How can I fix this?

```
    <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="container">
    <div id="slider" class="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
        <li><img class="image" src="image_1.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img class="image" src="image_2.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img class="image" src="image_3.jpg" /></li>
                <li><img class="image" src="image_4.jpg" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="captions">
    <ul class="slides">
    <li><p>Slide 1 caption</p></li>
        <li><p>Slide 2 caption</p></li>
        <li><p>Slide 3 caption</p></li>
        <li><p>Slide 4 caption</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="footerwrapper">
    <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides nd-gallery-list">     
        <li><img class="thumb" src="thumb_1.jpg"></li>
            <li><img class="thumb" src="thumb_2.jpg"></li>
            <li><img class="thumb" src="thumb_3.jpg"></li>
            <li><img class="thumb" src="thumb_4.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {

  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 103,
    itemMargin: 0,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });

  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    animationSpeed: 1,
    sync: "#carousel",
  });
});
  </script>
```

A link to the project : http://goo.gl/H715x

Greets,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*very-easy-and-dirty-trick*: if you remove the css property `position: absolute` from the .flex-caption selector the caption is placed below the image itself.
you can manually edit the .css file or remove dinamically via jQuery.

the result is not really the best in term of style, but you can achieve better results by doing some more modifications to the CSS.